# why does Angular 2 (4 really) Protractor E2E always times out while running ng e2e?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a basic test setup, but it always times out.  Nothing async happening, just trying to get to an input box.

- Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular

If i turn this off, I get this:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Error in Console

```
Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined
```

It is an Angular 4 app running with the Angular CLI

```
ng e2e
```

I've tried all the things in this FAQ that it recommends as well:  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular

Comment: Are you running timeouts somewhere?

Comment: I don't have anything running any kind of timeouts.  I have a simple input box and I'm able to have the test:

    <input id="shaneTest" value="TEST ME" />

Accessing it like this:

    element(by.id('shaneTest'))

Comment: I seem to be able to make this work with the following, but i'm sure it will bite me and is not quite right.  Test runs though:  

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

Comment: Maybe an interval ? I just had the same issue and the cause was an interval.